# how to subtract months giving a specific criteria

Tags: if-statement, monthcalendar

hi I have a rolling last 12 months in excel but I would like to exclude specific months so that way it will skip does months on the report. but the formula that I have wont work for every month. the months that I would like to skip is march 2020, april 2020, may 2020, june 2020. I have a drop list I which  it will subtract the last 12 months.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thUIB.png)

Comment: please include your formula in the quesion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is this an MS Excel question? Would the excel and/or the vba tag or similar be appropriate? Questions about a gazillion tools and programs are asked here, so to attract those who know about yours it’s a good idea to tag your question accordingly.